# removeEventListener callback not being called for event (beforeunload)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Event listener beforeunload in not removing in useEffect, why it can happens?

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect, FC } from 'react';

const beforeUnloadListener = (event: any) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  return (event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to exit?');
};

const OnClosePageDetector: FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener, { capture: true });
    return (): void => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default OnClosePageDetector;
```

Comment: how did you check it doesn't get called?

Comment: in browser console? tab event listeners

Comment: Haven't used that tab. Did you unmount the component? Put a `console.log` to make sure it didn't get called on unmount.

Comment: yes component is unmounting if I add some console.log in to return funtion its work

Comment: @egorchik, what I know is `beforeunload` is called before the page is closed, so how do you detect that it doesn't remove, and why do you need to remove it if the page is already will close ( because the whole app instance will be removed )?

Comment: I have modal window <Modal><OnClosePageDetector/><Modal/> when modal is closed event listener must be removed

Comment: Do you open new browser window for modal?

Comment: @antokhio no I stay in one browser page

Comment: @egorchik Then the modal isn't an window instance, so this event  prolly not the one you are looking for... Not sure you even need anything like event in there, likely if you do useEffect(()=> { return () => setSomething()}, []) you will get same result

Comment: Remove { capture: true }

Comment: @RitikBanger yes, this is an asnwer

Comment: @RitikBanger it will be more useful for OP and others, if you can also add explanation why removing that parameter should work

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava capture take a boolean value indicating that events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.

Comment: @RitikBanger  I checked that description also, but can't explain still why it doesn't remove the listener, when component unmounts

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava added the answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove capture: true from add event listener or add the same in remove event listener.

Also, In memory, it is possible that both add and remove are pointing to different locations due to different options provided.

The add event listener and remove event listener take the same param to work on a particular event. As we are registering the event listener- with the capture flag and removing without the flag, the side effects occur.

[Reference](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-remove-event-listener-not-working#:%7E:text=To%20resolve%20the%20removeEventListener%20not,will%20not%20remove%20the%20listener.)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `beforeUnloadListener` function inside of the function given to `useEffect` (which is the recommended way of doing it according to the official documentation)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, FC } from 'react';


const OnClosePageDetector: FC = () => {
    
  useEffect(() => {

    const beforeUnloadListener = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        return (event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to exit?');
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener, { capture: true });

    return (): void => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener);
    

  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default OnClosePageDetector;
```

Comment: event listener not removing ((

Answer (score 0):

solved, by removing param

```
{ capture: true }
```